# Entity framework code first with MySql server not able to run migration

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have setup two configuration for migration one is for SQL server and another is for MySql. SQL Server migration is now not being used. Now my problem is when I execute Sql Server migration with `Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName InTouchEnterprise.Data.Repository.MySqlMigrations.Configuration -verbose`. It gives me following error

> Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'test' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

But If I run the project it gets successfully connected to the database and do all the operation with database correctly. Now I am clue less what could have been wrong.

According to the error message it says that I am not specifying the password but I have specified password in the web.config. below is my connection string.

```
<add name="IdentityDB" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=rtd;uid=test;password=*******" />
```

Below is code for Configuration class:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<InTouchEnterprise.Data.Repository.InTouchEnterpriseDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        MigrationsDirectory = @"MySqlMigrations";

        //for mysql
        SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
    }

    protected override void Seed(InTouchEnterprise.Data.Repository.InTouchEnterpriseDbContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try this connection string instead `connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=rtd;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"` I think it's the connection string format that is invalid.

Comment: Do you have the right target project set when you run the migration through the package manager?

Comment: @jmesolomon Trying that connection string does not change any thing. It gives me same error.

Comment: @S.C. Yes I am sure I have right nuget package and startup package as -verbose flag logs are pointing to correct database.

Comment: Have you tried changing the connection string to a different database or user just to make sure your package manager is actually referencing the correct connection string and not a default-named one?

Comment: @S.C. Yes I have tried changing both database and user and both has been reflected in error message.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya Delete all the migration files in your .EntityFramework project under the Migrations folder. Then run `Add-Migration` again and then run `Update-Database`

Comment: @viveknuna It doesn't work.

Comment: Is this EF or EF Core?

Comment: @viveknuna It is EF.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact issue but when I added persist security info in connection string in web.config to true it started working again. Here is my updated connection string.

```
<add name="IdentityDB" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=rtd;uid=root;password=*****;persistsecurityinfo=True" />
```

Comment: Even with EF Core (2.2.0) this solution worked for me